# How to add text to value in console, without breaking it

Tags: javascript, console

so the code bellow would write ten numbers in the console. How could I add some text behind, lets say, number five? So it would write numbers like usual, but the number five would have also some text to it.

```js
for (let x = 1; x < 11; x++) {
console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to log "5" before the x number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more idea is to use `switch statement` (Could be more **readable** for a lot of cases "do something on 1" and "2" and "5" and so on).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

```html
<script>
 for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
   switch (i) {
     case 1:
       console.log("hello: " + i);
       break;
     case 5:
       console.log("hello: " + i);
       break;
     default:
       console.log(i);
   }
 }
</script>
```

> `default` Optional A default clause; if provided, this clause is
> executed if the value of expression doesn't match any of the case
> clauses.

** out of topic: it is more common to use `i` inside `for` loop (`i` == index).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a ternary condition that checks if `x` is 5.

```js
for (let x = 1; x < 11; x++) {
  console.log(x + (x == 5 ? ' text' : ''));
}
```

If you want the text before the number you can just move the expression like:

```
console.log((x == 5 ? 'text ' : '') + x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for(let x = 0; x < 11; x++) {
  if(x === 5) {
    console.log('number 5 and additional text');
  } else {
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```

if I understood your questioncorrectly, this should work

Comment: Yes, this is it! Would it be possible to write this with switch or if? I am kinda new into coding, those statements are for me easier to read, but thanks!

Comment: Sure. Updated with "if" condition. `Switch` example added by @Ezra Siton

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable to store all of the output. For example you want it to be space-separated then.

```js
let output = "";

for (let x = 1; x < 11; x++) {
 
  output += x + " ";

  if (x == 5) {
     output += "add something";
  }

}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out as soon as I get to computer. But will it write every value, I mean all the numbers from one to ten? Because into console log, you put only output, which in this case is only number five with that text.

Comment: absolutely every number, because before the `if` we add `x ` to `output`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a string (in this case `5`) to be added after each value. If so, [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will do that job for you.

```js
console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].map(item => item + '5'))
```

If you want to define `5` for specific values, you can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

See this example:

```js
// Select only odd numbers and then add the number 5 behind them
console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].filter(value => Math.abs(value % 2) === 1).map(item => item + '5'))
```